# iteration in html string format to create dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to iterate my data in HTML. in react HTML code is not compiled so I am adding the HTML code string by string and trying to iterate the table. and the whole HTML should be in string format. which is used to create a PDF file. but I am unable to iterate my data dynamically in HTML. please suggest the solution.
code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {Text, TouchableHighlight, View, Alert} from 'react-native';

import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';

const data = {
  headers: ['Name', 'Country', 'City', 'Mobile', 'Salary', 'Date', 'PAN'],

  rows: [
    ['Maxwell', 'Australia', 'Sydney', '123', '$22', '02/02/89', 'yes'],
    ['Mark', 'Canada', 'Toronto', '056', '$8965', '12/06/02', 'no'],
    ['David', 'United Kingdom', 'London', '242', 'S23', '25/02/20', ''],
    ['Kohli', 'India', 'Delhi', '8956', '$32', '04/12/21', 'yes'],
    ['ABD', 'RSA', 'captown', '4515', '$32', '2/11/08', null],
  ],
};

export default class PdfTest extends Component {
  async createPDF() {
    let options = {
      html:
        `
      <html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>` +
        `<h2>${data.headers[1]}</h2>

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>` +
        `</body>
</html>
      
  `,
      fileName: 'data20',
      directory: 'Documents',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
    // console.log(file.filePath);
    Alert.alert(file.filePath);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.createPDF}>
          <Text>Create PDF</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to loop through the two arrays.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        (async () => {
            try {

                const data = {
                    headers: ['Name', 'Country', 'City', 'Mobile', 'Salary', 'Date', 'PAN'],

                    rows: [
                        ['Maxwell', 'Australia', 'Sydney', '123', '$22', '02/02/89', 'yes'],
                        ['Mark', 'Canada', 'Toronto', '056', '$8965', '12/06/02', 'no'],
                        ['David', 'United Kingdom', 'London', '242', 'S23', '25/02/20', ''],
                        ['Kohli', 'India', 'Delhi', '8956', '$32', '04/12/21', 'yes'],
                        ['ABD', 'RSA', 'captown', '4515', '$32', '2/11/08', null],
                    ],
                };

                let [table, th, tr, td] = ['', '', '', ''];

                data.headers.forEach(element => {
                    th = th + '<th>' + element + '</th>';
                });

                data.rows.forEach(element => {
                    td = '';
                    element.forEach(element1 => {
                        td = td + '<td>' + element1 + '</td>';
                    });
                    tr = tr + '<tr>' + td + '</tr>';
                });


                table = '<tr>' + th + '</tr>' + '<tbody>' + tr + '</tbody>';
                document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;

            } catch (e) {
                // Deal with the fact the chain failed
                console.log(e);
            }
        })();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>table</title>
</head>

<body>
    table
    <div>
        <table id="table" border="1"></table>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```